# get total blocks on eos chain

Tags: api

Through one [these api endpoints](https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/), is there a request I can make to query the total number of blocks on the chain?

Answer (score 1):

https://api.eosdetroit.io/v1/chain/get_info

"head_block_num" or "last_irreversible_block_num" is the third or fourth value returned in JSON format respectively.